# Did you enable the php_fileinfo extension in Azure

Tags: php, azure, laravel

How can I enable `php_fileinfo` in an Azure website, for Laravel to determine whether the file is a PDF?

I tried to add the setting to Azure as shown in this image, but it's not working. Tried it without the `bin\etx\` directory as well.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this solution - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/8f8be9e1-7bfc-4a16-a65e-b80ff56dadc8/azure-web-site-phpfileinfodll?forum=windowsazuretroubleshooting

Comment: i think it is only bin\php_fileinfo.dll as shown here http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#EnableExtDefaultPHP

Comment: @ramiramilu, it's not :( tried.

Comment: Sounds like a question for vendor support.

Answer (score 2):

From the [comments](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/), have you tried:

> Use "PHP_Extensions" instead of "PHP_EXTENSIONS" to make it work properly